# CSipSimple implementation error

Tags: android, android-ndk

I am trying to compile CSipSimple sample project using ndk-build.but build failed with following error log.

```
D:\Android\android-ndk-r8-windows\android-ndk-r8>ndk-build.cmd
Android NDK: No local settings... build all in release mode !
D:\Android\android-ndk-r8-windows\android-ndk-r8\samples\CSipSimple/jni//webrtc/
android_toolchain/Android.mk:34: D:\Android\android-ndk-r8-windows\android-ndk-r
8\samples\CSipSimple/jni//webrtc/android_toolchain/../sources//system_wrappers/s
ource/Android.mk: No such file or directory
D:\Android\android-ndk-r8-windows\android-ndk-r8\samples\CSipSimple/jni//webrtc/
android_toolchain/Android.mk:35: D:\Android\android-ndk-r8-windows\android-ndk-r
8\samples\CSipSimple/jni//webrtc/android_toolchain/../sources//modules/audio_pro
cessing/utility/Android.mk: No such file or directory
D:\Android\android-ndk-r8-windows\android-ndk-r8\samples\CSipSimple/jni//webrtc/
android_toolchain/Android.mk:36: D:\Android\android-ndk-r8-windows\android-ndk-r
8\samples\CSipSimple/jni//webrtc/android_toolchain/../sources//common_audio/sign
al_processing/Android.mk: No such file or directory
D:\Android\android-ndk-r8-windows\android-ndk-r8\samples\CSipSimple/jni//webrtc/
android_toolchain/Android.mk:37: D:\Android\android-ndk-r8-windows\android-ndk-r
8\samples\CSipSimple/jni//webrtc/android_toolchain/../sources//common_audio/vad/
Android.mk: No such file or directory
D:\Android\android-ndk-r8-windows\android-ndk-r8\samples\CSipSimple/jni//webrtc/
android_toolchain/Android.mk:38: D:\Android\android-ndk-r8-windows\android-ndk-r
8\samples\CSipSimple/jni//webrtc/android_toolchain/../sources//common_audio/resa
mpler/Android.mk: No such file or directory
D:\Android\android-ndk-r8-windows\android-ndk-r8\samples\CSipSimple/jni//webrtc/
android_toolchain/Android.mk:41: D:\Android\android-ndk-r8-windows\android-ndk-r
8\samples\CSipSimple/jni//webrtc/android_toolchain/../sources//modules/audio_pro
cessing/aecm/Android.mk: No such file or directory
D:\Android\android-ndk-r8-windows\android-ndk-r8\samples\CSipSimple/jni//webrtc/
android_toolchain/Android.mk:42: D:\Android\android-ndk-r8-windows\android-ndk-r
8\samples\CSipSimple/jni//webrtc/android_toolchain/../sources//modules/audio_pro
cessing/aec/Android.mk: No such file or directory
D:\Android\android-ndk-r8-windows\android-ndk-r8\samples\CSipSimple/jni//webrtc/
android_toolchain/Android.mk:46: D:\Android\android-ndk-r8-windows\android-ndk-r
8\samples\CSipSimple/jni//webrtc/android_toolchain/../sources//modules/audio_cod
ing/main/source/Android.mk: No such file or directory
D:\Android\android-ndk-r8-windows\android-ndk-r8\samples\CSipSimple/jni//webrtc/
android_toolchain/Android.mk:47: D:\Android\android-ndk-r8-windows\android-ndk-r
8\samples\CSipSimple/jni//webrtc/android_toolchain/../sources//modules/audio_cod
ing/neteq/Android.mk: No such file or directory
D:\Android\android-ndk-r8-windows\android-ndk-r8\samples\CSipSimple/jni//webrtc/
android_toolchain/Android.mk:48: D:\Android\android-ndk-r8-windows\android-ndk-r
8\samples\CSipSimple/jni//webrtc/android_toolchain/../sources//modules/audio_cod
ing/codecs/cng/Android.mk: No such file or directory
D:\Android\android-ndk-r8-windows\android-ndk-r8\samples\CSipSimple/jni//webrtc/
android_toolchain/Android.mk:49: D:\Android\android-ndk-r8-windows\android-ndk-r
8\samples\CSipSimple/jni//webrtc/android_toolchain/../sources//modules/audio_cod
ing/codecs/g711/Android.mk: No such file or directory
D:\Android\android-ndk-r8-windows\android-ndk-r8\samples\CSipSimple/jni//webrtc/
android_toolchain/Android.mk:50: D:\Android\android-ndk-r8-windows\android-ndk-r
8\samples\CSipSimple/jni//webrtc/android_toolchain/../sources//modules/audio_cod
i    ng/codecs/ilbc/Android.mk: No such file or directory
D:\Android\android-ndk-r8-windows\android-ndk-r8\samples\CSipSimple/jni//webrtc/
android_toolchain/Android.mk:52: D:\Android\android-ndk-r8-windows\android-ndk-r
8\samples\CSipSimple/jni//webrtc/android_toolchain/../sources//modules/audio_cod
ing/codecs/iSAC/fix/source/Android.mk: No such file or directory
D:\Android\android-ndk-r8-windows\android-ndk-r8\samples\CSipSimple/jni//webrtc/
android_toolchain/Android.mk:53: D:\Android\android-ndk-r8-windows\android-ndk-r
8\samples\CSipSimple/jni//webrtc/android_toolchain/../sources//modules/audio_cod
ing/codecs/iSAC/main/source/Android.mk: No such file or directory
D:\Android\android-ndk-r8-windows\android-ndk-r8\samples\CSipSimple/jni//webrtc/
android_toolchain/Android.mk:56: D:\Android\android-ndk-r8-windows\android-ndk-r
8\samples\CSipSimple/jni//webrtc/android_toolchain/../sources//modules/audio_pro
cessing/ns/Android.mk: No such file or directory
D:\Android\android-ndk-r8-windows\android-ndk-r8\samples\CSipSimple/jni//webrtc/
android_toolchain/Android.mk:64: D:\Android\android-ndk-r8-windows\android-ndk-r
8\samples\CSipSimple/jni//webrtc/android_toolchain/../sources//common_video/liby
uv/Android.mk: No such file or directory
D:\Android\android-ndk-r8-windows\android-ndk-r8\samples\CSipSimple/jni//webrtc/
android_toolchain/Android.mk:65: D:\Android\android-ndk-r8-windows\android-ndk-r
8\samples\CSipSimple/jni//webrtc/android_toolchain/../sources//modules/video_ren
der/main/source/Android.mk: No such file or directory
D:\Android\android-ndk-r8-windows\android-ndk-r8\samples\CSipSimple/jni//webrtc/
android_toolchain/Android.mk:66: D:\Android\android-ndk-r8-windows\android-ndk-r
8\samples\CSipSimple/jni//webrtc/android_toolchain/../sources//modules/video_cap
ture/main/source/Android.mk: No such file or directory
D:\Android\android-ndk-r8-windows\android-ndk-r8\samples\CSipSimple/jni//opus/an
droid_toolchain/Android.mk:22: D:\Android\android-ndk-r8-windows\android-ndk-r8\
samples\CSipSimple/jni//opus/android_toolchain/../sources//silk_sources.mk: No s
uch file or directory
D:\Android\android-ndk-r8-windows\android-ndk-r8\samples\CSipSimple/jni//opus/an
droid_toolchain/Android.mk:32: D:\Android\android-ndk-r8-windows\android-ndk-r8\
samples\CSipSimple/jni//opus/android_toolchain/../sources//celt_sources.mk: No s
uch file or directory
D:\Android\android-ndk-r8-windows\android-ndk-r8\samples\CSipSimple/jni//opus/an
droid_toolchain/Android.mk:34: D:\Android\android-ndk-r8-windows\android-ndk-r8\
samples\CSipSimple/jni//opus/android_toolchain/../sources//opus_sources.mk: No s
uch file or directory
D:\Android\android-ndk-r8-windows\android-ndk-r8\samples\CSipSimple/jni/Android.
mk:24: D:\Android\android-ndk-r8-windows\android-ndk-r8\samples\CSipSimple/jni//
openssl/sources/Android.mk: No such file or directory
D:\Android\android-ndk-r8-windows\android-ndk-r8\samples\CSipSimple/jni//openssl
/android_toolchain/Android.mk:41: D:\Android\android-ndk-r8-windows\android-ndk-
r8\samples\CSipSimple/jni//openssl/android_toolchain/../sources//android-config.
mk: No such file or directory
D:\Android\android-ndk-r8-windows\android-ndk-r8\samples\CSipSimple/jni//openssl
/android_toolchain/Android.mk:59: D:\Android\android-ndk-r8-windows\android-ndk-
r8\samples\CSipSimple/jni//openssl/android_toolchain/../sources//android-config.
mk: No such file or directory
Android NDK: ERROR:D:\Android\android-ndk-r8-windows\android-ndk-r8\samples\CSip
Simple/jni//csipsimple-wrapper/android_toolchain/Android.mk:gcc: LOCAL_SRC_FILES
 points to a missing file
Android NDK: Check that //D:/Android/android-ndk-r8-windows/android-ndk-r8/toolc
hains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/windows/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-andr
oideabi/4.4.3/libgcc.a exists  or that its path is correct
D:/Android/android-ndk-r8-windows/android-ndk-r8/build/core/prebuilt-library.mk:
43: *** Android NDK: Aborting    .  Stop.
```

not getting error.if anyone has implemented please help to solve error.I have downloaded this project from this URL http://code.google.com/p/csipsimple/source/checkout. please let me know where I am doing wrong.

Thanks In advance.
Regards,
Ashwini Shelke

Comment: Check this out may it heps you, http://stackoverflow.com/q/11846236/696602

Answer (score 5):

It's absolutely not a CSipSimple implementation error.

The problem is that you didn't read the documentation !!!!!

**Please read : http://code.google.com/p/csipsimple/wiki/HowToBuild**

Also, I would advise you to leave your Windows and switch to an actual developer environment (gnu/linux based). Else you'll probably understand nothing on what you do and spend a lot of time trying to understand how the GNU toolchain work, while it's obvious for a developer using gnu/linux env.

CSipSimple much more complicate that a very simple ndk application and involves a lot of other projects. So the toolchain to build it involves step to fetch remote projects using svn:externals, git, zip, quilt. It also generates jni interfaces using swig tool.

Also take care of the license of the project.

For other question you can also join the CSipSimple developer google group (the link is in the HowToBuild wiki page).

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to copy pjsip generated code into D:\CSipSimple-trunk\CSipSimple\src\org\pjsip directory. Then clean project and build it.

Comment: You could improve your answer by adding documentation reference, a more generic solution and/or further information, like how to clean.