# sipdroid - Another incoming call is not display while one is continue

Tags: java, android, sip, voip, sipdroid

I have installed **SIPDROID**. I made three account at sip2sip.
After that I have configured application using one of that account. Application works fine.

**Question is:** If I make multiple call to the same phone using SIP is there anyway to handle all calls at a same time? 

Another incoming call is not displaying on mobile screen while first call is continue.
The first call getting picked up but what about the second call which is coming during first call.
Even second call is not displaying on the screen. Confused !!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Sipdroid](http://code.google.com/p/sipdroid/) that I what started with but after researching on it and from developers reviews I found that application has some missing functionality like multiple call and transferring calls etc...

I don't know but may who is **expert in sip stack or have time to do** can implement missing functionality but I am neither one of them so my desire to get an application that have all this functionality and by modifying it I can integrate into my application and [csipsimple](http://code.google.com/p/csipsimple/) is the answer.

However its not easy job to build csipsimple into windows environment but there is hack how to do it. so carefully read its [wiki](http://code.google.com/p/csipsimple/wiki/HowToBuild#For_Windows) about building project into window environment.

According to wiki you can [build native library](http://code.google.com/p/csipsimple/wiki/HowToBuild#Build_native_library) or you can go ahead [without building the native library](http://code.google.com/p/csipsimple/wiki/HowToBuild#Without_building_the_native_library). I suggest for windows user to go with  [without building the native library](http://code.google.com/p/csipsimple/wiki/HowToBuild#Without_building_the_native_library).

If you have read wiki then in *"without building the native library"* section last line is like

> "*To get the .so files, download latest nightly build from nightly
>   build website and unpack the apk file (apk files are just zip files).
>   Then get lib/ARCH/.so files and copy it into CSipSimple
>   libs/ARCH/.so*"

**I have to clarify one important thing about that:**

First get [.apk](http://nightlies.csipsimple.com/trunk/) file of csipsimple. The version of ***.apk*** file must same to download version of your [csipsimple source code.](http://code.google.com/p/csipsimple/source/browse/trunk/CSipSimple).

Here, you can see the source code version. Download the same version [.apk](http://nightlies.csipsimple.com/trunk/) and do further as described in wiki.
[image]

Comment: I have apk file downloaded from nightly build website, how to unpack that apk file to get the .so file. i was downloaded csipsimple form the svn and imported into eclipse, what have to do next for working, help me on i was stuck at this form the last 2 weeks.

Comment: .apk file is nothing else but its one type of .zip package. You can extract by right click on it as we do for .zip package.

Comment: i am getting this error java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError and 08-NoClassDefFoundError: org.pjsip.pjsua.pjsuaConstants i have this class in the src folder.Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: PJSUA_SDP_SESS_HAS_CONN_get , org.pjsip.pjsua.pjsuaJNI.PJSUA_SDP_SESS_HAS_CONN_get(Native Method)

Comment: Finally i got solution from your answer and suggestions, thanks @Priyank

Answer (score 5):

SipDroid supports **only one *line*** at all times. This means you cannot have conference calls. So to the question:

> If I make multiple call to the same phone using SIP is there anyway to
>   handle all calls at a same time?

Nope, you cannot handle simultaneous calls at the same time. Fortunately there's another open source SIP Client that supports multiple lines - [IMSDroid](http://code.google.com/p/imsdroid/).
Though you can extend SipDroid to support multiple lines, that's a lot of effort. The main objects you have to pay attention to in order to support multiple lines are: 
`UserAgent`, `SipProvider` (note that it's designed to support multiplexing/demultiplexing of SIP messages), `JAudioLauncher` and the `Call` object.

The bug you're describing with the second call not showing is not something I have witnessed. This could be due to your device setup, or due to customizations performed on the original code...

Comment: Can [csipsimple](http://code.google.com/p/csipsimple/) be the alternative of sipdroid ? because I am quite familiar with [csipsimple](http://code.google.com/p/csipsimple/). I have imported both projects then installed both appllication(.apk Generated by sourcce code).  csipsimple was continues failed in registering so I go with sipdroid. But after that face mul. calling problem in sipdroid. Which side I should go?

Comment: I have also used csipsimple, never had problems with registration on a custom Asterisk and Kamailio servers, but the registration in sip2sip is more complicated because of the proxy and the relays. Though I think csipsimple also should be able to register in sip2sip. Have you looked in any document that shows how the configuration in csipsimple looks (to connect to sip2sip)?

Comment: I can easily register to csip if I directly download its apk from [here](http://code.google.com/p/csipsimple/downloads/list). What I did, I have imported its [source](http://code.google.com/p/csipsimple/source/browse/trunk/CSipSimple) in eclipse and then after many struggling I build it without any error and generated .apk in *bin folder*, I installed. But my account status is only remains *inactive* even it's not process for registering. that's second thing if I do some mistake to fill up server name etc... At-least it has to start register process. This all problem I getting in my build apk.

Comment: well that's a completely different matter from the sipDroid multi-line support. The problems in the csip you have could be due to your modifications or incorrect build process - one could only guess....

Answer (score 4):

you can build the csipsimple easily in linux OS... All you have to do is just paste the download source link in linux commanpropmt and for windows you must have latest cygwin software to download or to build native library... Better option is to go for linux OS only...

Comment: Yes Ramesh, that I know, but this is all about window os. But I solved it.:)